# RegEx to check if word starts with search character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a RegEx to find words which starts with my search text.

When I run this program I get following output :

True start: 3 end: 6

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(("kh(\\w)"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String test = "Shakhir Khan";
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
System.out.println(m.find()+" start : "+m.start()+" end : "+m.end());
```

What I want is it should find 'Kh' from `Khan` and not from `Shakhir`. It should find only at start and not in middle of word.

Answer (score 1):

Use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

```
Pattern.compile(("\\bkh(\\w)"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
                  ^^
```

Word boundary will not consider special symbols, for that

```
(^|\b|\s)kh
```

`^` is starts with anchor, `|` is OR condition in regex. `\b` is word boundary, `\s` matches space characters.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/f2BUvk/2)